# How to make Control Flow Graph of a user defined code at run time

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio-2010, testing, control-flow-graph

Suppose User write some code in edit text (TextBox or else) and program recognize all **definitions** and **uses** . Now program wants to show Control Flow Graph using ability of Eclipse of making CFG.

1. Is it possible ?
2. Can we Use some other Tool Built in Capability of Making CFG to show CFG of userDefined code like Visual Studio?

I am Talking about any kinds of App ,Applications (Windows Form ,Android etc)

Comment: trying to do something similar but stuck in making CFG and analyzing it. Have you got any progress.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, using ability of Eclipse for making CFG. You can try any other method

Comment: You can assist me , Any y method?